# Expose docker containers running in bridge network to localhost

Tags: docker, graphql-federation

I am running multiple containers for GQL Federation 2 with Apollo Router.

I need to create the supergraph using rover cli, so I am running the containers in custom bridge network, and exposing their ports mapping them to different ports on localhost, however, when I try to access it from localhost, the server throws `connection refused`.

Here is example of my docker-compose.yaml
`version: '3.9'

```
services:
  users-service:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: apps/account-api/Dockerfile
    container_name: users-service
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - custom-bridge
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./users-service:/usr/src/app/users-service
  therapy-service:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: apps/therapy-api/Dockerfile
    container_name: therapy-service
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3002:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - custom-bridge
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./therapy-service:/usr/src/app/therapy-service
  patientcard-service:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: apps/patientcard-api/Dockerfile
    container_name: patientcard-service
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3003:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - custom-bridge
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./patientcard-service:/usr/src/app/patientcard-service
  notifications-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: apps/notifications-api/Dockerfile
    container_name: notifications-service
    restart: always
    networks:
      - custom-bridge
    ports:
      - "3007:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./notifications-service:/usr/src/app/notifications-service
  gateway-router:
    image: ghcr.io/apollographql/router:v1.13.0
    container_name: gateway-router
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - users-service
      - therapy-service
      - patientcard-service
      - postgres
      # - drugs-api
    volumes:
      - ./apps/api/src/supergraph-schema.graphql:/supergraph-schema.graphql
      - ./apps/api/src/router.yaml:/router.yaml
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - custom-bridge
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./.tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5444:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=******
      - POSTGRES_USER=******
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=******
    networks:
      - custom-bridge
  redis:
    image: redis:7-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '6333:6379'
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass googleisshit
    volumes: 
      - ./.tmp/redis:/data
    networks:
    - custom-bridge

networks:
  custom-bridge:
    driver: bridge`
```

I am also exposing port 3000 in every Dockerfile and every service is listening on that port.
When I run the service locally it works.

I guess my question is "Does the docker bridge network even expose containers for localhost on the host machine?"

I tried exposing the containers this way and expected to connect to each with localhost:[port], but it doesn't budge.

### Edit

`docker ps` returns this

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE  COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS   PORTS   NAMES
1ae84817cd54   ghcr.io/apollographql/router:v1.13.0   "/dist/router_wrappe…"   20 hours ago   Restarting (1) 10 seconds ago                            gateway-router
7734b35b7411   molecula-backend-patientcard-service   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 hours ago   Up 20 hours                     0.0.0.0:3003->3000/tcp   patientcard-service
c9970e456668   molecula-backend-users-service         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 hours ago   Up 20 hours                     0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   users-service
c9ee007cbe22   molecula-backend-therapy-service       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 hours ago   Up 20 hours                     0.0.0.0:3002->3000/tcp   therapy-service
22c4d96305fe   postgres                               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 hours ago   Up 20 hours                     0.0.0.0:5444->5432/tcp   molecula-backend-postgres-1
60621dd7f92b   redis:7-alpine                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 hours ago   Up 20 hours                     0.0.0.0:6333->6379/tcp   molecula-backend-redis-1
```

So I suppose I should reach the containers from my localhost, but the message says that "localhost didn't send any data".

Also I just realized that I can reach postgreSQL via postico on localhost:5444 without a problem, thus it my applications should be exposed to localhost as well.

### Edit Resolved

It seems that commenting `volumes` in docker-compose.yaml solved this issue. It seems that mounting volumes made the application run inconsistently and produced these access problems I have described earlier.
Mounting volumes was supposed to prevent bcrypt being compiled against different OS, but apparently my solution produced more errors than it resolved.

Comment: What piece is trying to connect to the individual services, and what error do you get?  When you say "on localhost" do you mean the host system outside a container, or one of the other container-specific localhosts, or `localhost` as seen from a GraphQL client like GraphiQL?  Can you directly call one of the individual services?

Comment: (Also consider cutting down the Compose file to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.  Do you need all of the services, or will just one show it?  Do you need custom `networks:` at all or will the Compose-provided `default` network work?  Do you need to manually set `container_name:`, or use `volumes:` to replace the images' code?)

Comment: At host machine, you can ping to docker container if you expose it (bridge network). for example with nginx: `docker run -itd --rm -p 80:80 --name stormbreaker nginx`, and nginx is available at `http://localhost/`

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for reply, the docker network is running locally with all containers being run on my computer and I try to access each service via web browser on localhost:[portnumber]. Somehow it doesn't work and I get "localhost didn't send any data" message with `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error.

Comment: @ManhDo when I run only one container and plug it in the docker network, I can get to localhost:3000/graphql and it actually opens the playground. The setup is the same, the only difference is that I ran the container separately and not as part of `docker compose`.

Comment: @Reabon, No. you can use docker-compose or not as long as, you put all docker containers into same network. For example, I can put `stormbreaker` container to other bridge network by `docker run -itd --rm --network asgard -p 80:80 --name stormbreaker nginx `, you must create network asgard first to every container can undertand each other, containers  on different network can not ping each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting `volumes` inside the `docker-compose.yaml` solved the issue as mounting these volumes was producing inconsistent application.

Mounting these volumes was supposed to help with bcrypt build as referenced in [Install Bcrypt in Docker by Richard Kotze](https://www.richardkotze.com/top-tips/install-bcrypt-docker-image-exclude-host-node-modules), but in my case produced more bugs than it resolved.